# Make a <style> CSS Script into a Greasemonkey Script

Tags: html, css, greasemonkey

I have the following CSS code:

```
<style>
.crumbContTop > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > th:nth-child(1)     {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 98%;
}

#navMenuContainer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#navBar > div:nth-child(1) {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
    right:0px;
}

#navBar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    width:4000px;
    height:15px;
}

td.cell1 {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:1;
    padding:20px;
    right:0px;
    opacity:0.7;
    visibility:visible !important;
}

#main-header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px !important;
    z-index:1 !important;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
```

I just want to convert it into a Greasemonkey script, basically this Fixes the position of the Nav Bars which are on top and on the bottom of the screen.
The problem is that greasemonkey is telling me that it is expecting an identifier instead of " < ".

any help?

thanks.

(One more question, how do I make the position static, but when the object is out of screen it becomes fixed?)

Comment: Setting style is covered in the Greasemonkey manual: http://greasemonkey.win-start.de/patterns/set-style.html. That not work?

Comment: @SlightlyCuban I just don't know how to convert the commands into Greasemonkey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Edit:

As Hellion pointed out, this is covered by Greasemonkey with [`GM_addStyle`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_addStyle). From the wiki:

```
GM_addStyle("body { color: white; } /* CSS etc, etc */");
```

Greasemonkey is just JS, so you can't directly use CSS in a Greasemonkey script; you need to inject it into the page somehow.

#### Original Answer:

Demonstrated on http://www.techradar.com/us/news/internet/the-beginner-s-guide-to-greasemonkey-scripting-598247/2, you could add a function to add a stylesheet to the page, then store your CSS in a string:

```
function addCss(cssString) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var newCss = document.createElement('style');
    newCss.type = "text/css";
    newCss.innerHTML = cssString;
    head.appendChild(newCss);
}
```

And at some point in your script call `addCss` on your current CSS:

```
addCss("#mainHeader { position:fixed;} /* more CSS here */");
```

Comment: You don't like `GM_addStyle()` ?

Comment: @Hellion +1 calling me out on that one. I guess the only need for `addCss` is to make your script more non-Greasemonkey portable.